# Relationship job, users in models one to many?

Tags: django-models

What is the best way to link this tables, sorry I am new in Django and I need a little bit of help with this, I got 3 tables:

1. Users
2. Jobs  ---> has an author field which is a user...
3. Applied

So I want the users to apply to jobs that they haven't published and they can only apply once.

So what I got at the moment is this:

```
class Applied(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('userenter code here', 'job',)
```

This works however if I try to apply for the same job twice it throws me an error.

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "job_applied_user_id_job_id_c38a42a4_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, job_id)=(1, 6) already exists.
```

This is my model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=4)
```

This is my view :

```
def apply(request, id):
  print "the %s has applied " %(request.user.username)
  job = Job.objects.get(pk=id)

  if job.author == request.user:
    messages.warning(request, 'You cannot apply to jobs you have publish')
  else:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    applied = Applied(user = user, job = job)
    if applied.not_applied_before():
      applied.save()
      messages.success(request, 'applied to job success')
    else:
      messages.info(request, 'You apply to this job already')
```